# Express summation in terms of matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Express the following 
$$\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ ({ \beta  }_{ 1 }x_{ i }+{ \beta  }_{ 0 }-y_{ i })^{ 2 } }$$

To become something of the form:
$∥Ax−b∥^{ 2 }$ where $A$ is an $m$−by−$n$ matrix and $b$ is an $m$−by−$1$ matrix. Note that $x$ is an $n$−by−$1$ matrix. We need to find explicitly $A$ and $b$ in terms of $x_{ 1 },...,x_{ n }$ and $y_{ 1 },...,y_{ n }$.

Comment: Next time use $\LaTeX$ *only* for mathematical symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Try going the opposite direction: Starting with a matrices $A$ and $b$, with components $A_{i j}$ and $b_{i}$ respectively, what would that matrix norm look like when expressed in terms of components? What $A_{i j}$ and $b_i$ will then give you the form you want?

Comment: I get that $||Ax-b||^2 = \sum _{ i=1 }^{ M }{ (\sum _{ j=1 }^{ N }{ { a }_{ ij }x_{ j }-{ b }_{ i } } )^{ 2 } } $. What i'm unable to understand is how to match $\beta_1x_i+\beta_0$ to the ax summation...

Comment: Never mind.. got it!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful. @JKMath